# Why are files not being filtered through my data factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I'm copying data from on-prem files to blob azure storage. The first part of the pipeline is exactly that, pulling the last modified file from on-prem to blob storage (blob_input). After that I'm having problems. I have one file out of 5 that doesn't have actual data but only shows "no data" which makes it impossible to transport to sql, that's the ultimate goal. So I connected my "copy data" to the filtering pipeline that I created. However, my pipeline doesn't filter out the file. Could someone tell me what my pipeline is missing? I have added pictures below to make things clearer but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post more so I have created a google docs with all the info  [Files and Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaVYl.png) [forEach1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqF4z.png) [forEach2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4kPK.png) [forEach3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZyNp.png) [lookup1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L5x7.png) [ifcondition1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU7Pk.png) [copydata1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dhnh.png) [copydata2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwqeD.png)

Comment: `@not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.count,1))` this condition is cheaching the count of lookup is equal to 1 or not if you are using first row as header then the lookup count for that file is 0 which is not equal to 1 in that case you 
 can use this condition `@greater(activity('Lookup1').output.count,0)` it will filter file if the lookup count is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario the problem causing to filter file where it contains only `no data` is **you are using first row as header then the lookup count for that file is 0 which is not equal to 1** because of it is not filtering out that file.

#### To resolve this, you can try:

This condition
`@greater(activity('Lookup1').output.count,0)`, it will filter file if the lookup count is greater than 0.
[image]

**Output**
Copy activity is not coping data from `daily4` file because it has sample input like you, and it failed in if condition.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing it from 1 to 0 helped, thank you Pratik!